# I am trying to read data from serial to use port on pc

Tags: reactjs, typescript, serial-port, react-typescript, usbserial

I am trying to read data from the serial to use port on pc

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const port = new SerialPort(PortName, { baudRate: BaudRate }, (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error opening port:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Serial port opened successfully.');
            }
        });
```

I am getting error as
`This expression is not constructable. Type 'typeof import(/node_modules/serialport/dist/index) has no construct signatures.`

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const port = new SerialPort(PortName, { baudRate: BaudRate }, (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error opening port:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Serial port opened successfully.');
            }
        });
```